# How do I animate things on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This [theme demo](http://demo.cms-theme.net/?theme=wp_medico) on themeforest has neat animations including for example showing text when the users scrolls down, or making icons appear from the sides.

I'm guessing CSS3 and JavaScript, possibly with jQuery or a framework specialized in animations would be used for this, but I have no idea where to start learning how to accomplish these kinds of animations.

Where do I start?

Comment: the animations in your example are very easily done with javascript or jQuery. Where do you start ? well if you ask this, definitely you need to start with the basics of javascript/jquery . For scroll animations you need to learn about `scroll()` event, maybe `offset()` or `position()` ( regarding the element you want to animate ) . I suggest you do not use libraries before you learn how they work and use them only for very big projects. I also strongly suggest you try and make your own ( simple at first ) animations and then work your way up. Do not try to eat the pie starting from the middle

Comment: *unless you don't mind getting dirty... very very dirty...

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [WowJS](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/).
And try going through their [source code](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW) if you're curious about it works under the hood.

Otherwise its a pretty good library to get started with scroll animations.

Comment: +1 WowJS is a nice idea - seems to fit the needs. When you said going through their source code, first I thought you meant using "inspection tools" on the theme site he linked, and thought that was a good idea too, though perhaps a bit involved without strong basics in web animation. - The github link also includes documentation on how to use, which is good. The actual code only contains comments in the coffee script files as far as I could see and not many - unless I looked in the wrong place

Comment: You're looking at the right place. Ya, you'll have to understand the source code and not just the comments. But, the gist is there's a scroll event listener that adds/removes classes to the elements, see [scrollCallback](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/blob/master/src/wow.coffee#L255). (I think). Didn't realise its in coffeescript, not a good source to go through if you're just starting :)

Comment: Which I'm not, but he is.

Answer (score 1):

Basically animations that are triggered by scrolling actions are Javascript / jQuery stuff (not CSS). There's a nice JS plugin which you can take a look at which helps to do all that: Scrollmagic, to be found [here](http://scrollmagic.io/)

Comment: Done properly the JS just changes a class at the appropriate time and the CSS (hooking into the classes) applies that to the page, no?

Comment: It doesn't only work with classes, it can as well animate parameters.

Comment: True, not everything can be implemented with classes... - especially when there's complex math involved, then inline style can be smoother. - Or if working with something more complex like SVG

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Wordpress, chances are you can buy a theme that includes very nice animations ready for use with a few options (say how fast it should occur or such) - similarly there are many neat animations on [codepen](https://codepen.io/brandonkennedy/pen/epRBYN) and similar sites so maybe if you search long enough you could find and copy what you want.

However, if you really want to learn how to do that yourself, there's no short cuts and you have to start with understanding JavaScript and the capabilities of CSS3 animations and deeply, so you know which can do what.

[CSS Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), [CSS Animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), [Simple JS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp)

These are all w3school tutorials but there are many other resources out there. Start with something simple and work your way up.

Since you mentioned the behavior on scroll, the relevant JavaScript is

```
object.addEventListener("scroll", myScript);
```

Here's a simple [use case](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll3) to start.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of ways to do it, but jQuery works nicely.

You may find [this](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/) and [this](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/) helpful.

```js
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($('body').scrollTop() > 110) {
      $('.box').css({
        'width': '50px',
        'height': '50px',
        'background': 'coral'
      });
    } else {
      $('.box').css({
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px',
        'background': 'red'
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 175px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  height: 600px;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 150px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin:  0 auto;
  transition: all .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
</div>
```